# Google Maps API v3 getPanoramaByLocation (StreetView)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I'm working on a project that picks random locations world-wide and need some functionality from Google Street View.  I'm working with API v3 of Google Maps. The question I have is with the getPanoramaByLocation method.  According to the Google docs, getPanoramaByLocation is :

"Retrieves the StreetViewPanoramaData for a panorama within a given radius of the given LatLng. The StreetViewPanoramaData is passed to the provided callback. If the radius is less than 50 meters, the nearest panorama will be returned."

The part I'm interested in is where it says "less than 50 meters, returns nearest panorama."  So, for example, if I put in coordinates for somewhere in the middle of the Congo (where there isn't a street view for miles and miles), it should return a panorama of the nearest available street view.  But it's not, it's returning null every time.

Is there a limit to how far away it looks?

Here's my Fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/nrJBP/1/

Thanks all, and hopefully this helps anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service searches within the radius you give, as the docs state. You specify the maximum radius.

The service could find *any* Panorama data within the radius, except if you specify 50m, when it will always find the nearest (within that 50m).

Comment: The way they write it could be interpreted in two different ways.  This line needs to be clarified : "If the radius is less than 50 meters, the nearest panorama will be returned."  This could mean that if I put in 1 meter for my radius, it would return the nearest panorama within any distance.  By what it's returning now, I'm guessing that it needs to be within whatever radius I put in.  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Andrew, do you know of any way to accomplish what I had above?  Basically supplying any set of coordinates worldwide, and find the nearest pano?

Comment: @efru: I can't think it would be particularly useful, I'm afraid. Click in the Congo and get a StreetView in Lagos (or wherever)? Why? It has no relation to the selected point. That said, what happens if you use a ridiculously large radius?

Comment: The project is a school project that doesn't necessarily have to show views within a certain distance.  If I use a very large radius it continues to show the same pano over and over again.  If I put in something like '99999999' it shows London, and if I put in 1234567 it, once again, shows London.  It doesn't randomize the returned pano's at all.  Maybe what I'm looking for isn't supported :(

Comment: It's behaving consistently with the docs (and my answer). It finds a panorama. I'm afraid I can't see a real-world use case for what you want to achieve, and Google will only expend effort in making real-world cases happen. TL:DR: I don't think it is supported.

Comment: The line from the documentation can be re-phrased as follows: if radius is >= 50 meters, zero or one result will be returned. If radius is < 50 meters, one result will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `google.maps.StreetViewStatus`. If the request was successful, it will return `OK`. If there are no nearby panoramas, it will return `ZERO_RESULTS`.